# Удаление с условием по списку в sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Как массово удалить записи по условию со списком? Проблема с формированием запроса. Пробовал так, не получается.

```
print(arKeys) # ['14', '17', '22']
arKeysStr = ", ".join(map(lambda x: "'" + x + "'", arKeys))
print(arKeysStr) # '14', '17', '22'
sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (?)"
self.cursor.execute(sql, (arKeysStr,))
```

Если выполнить

```
sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN ('14', '17', '22')"
self.cursor.execute(sql)
```

То запрос корректно выполняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал такую конструкцию

```
sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN ("+arKeysStr+")"
self.cursor.execute(sql)
```